# How do I select records in MySQL with multiple columns matching map of values?

Tags: mysql

I have the following 3-column table:

`+----+---------+------------+
| ID |  First  |    Last    |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 | Maurice | Richard    |
|  2 | Yvan    | Cournoyer  |
|  3 | Carey   | Price      |
|  4 | Guy     | Lafleur    |
|  5 | Steve   | Shutt      |
+----+---------+------------+`

If I want to look for everyone in `(Maurice,Guy)` I can do `select * from table where first in (Maurice,Guy)`.

If I want to find just `Maurice Richard`, I can do `select * from table where first = "Maurice" and last = "Richard"`.

How do I do a map, an array of multiples?

`[
  [Maurice, Richard]
  [Guy,Lafleur]
  [Yvan,Cournoyer]
]`

If I have an arbitrary number of entries, I cannot construct a long complex `where (first = "Maurice" and last = "Richard") or (first = "Guy" and last = "Lafleur") or ....`.

How do I do the moral equivalent of `where (first, last) in ((Guy,Lafleur),(Maurice,Richard))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just like you describe it:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (first, last) IN (('Guy','Lafleur'),('Maurice','Richard'))
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a815/1)

Comment: Uh... because I thought that was invalid. I just made up that syntax based on the normal `where somecol in (opt1, opt2, opt3)` to describe what I wanted. I always thought that you couldn't do that! Really? I can? So funny!

Comment: Well, it really does work. Thanks for the fiddle! Hats off! (apparently it is too quick, it won't let me accept the answer yet. Sorry about that. will do so in 3 mins when it lets me)